# Compare a column with 2 other different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm searching a way to get the differences between 3 tables.The main task that i can't do is to compare a column form table a and depends on what it contains, it compare with table b and c on 2 column.
An example will clarify what i'm trying to do:

```
Table A:
IpAddress    |HostName
10.10.01.10  | somethingtada
255.255.255.1| something.else

Table B:
IpAddress    |HostName            |Name
10.10.01.10  |somethingtada.tada  |somethingtada

Table C:
IpAddress    |HostName        |Name
255.255.255.1| something.else |something
1.1.1.1      | blabla.tada    |tada
```

And I need to have a table that show me the data like that

```
IpAddress    |HostName          |TableA|TableB|TableC
10.10.01.10  |somethingtada.tada|1     |1     |0
255.255.255.1|something.else    |1     |0     |1
1.1.1.1      |blabla.tada       |0     |0     |1
```

So if its not clear enough, when i have a "." in the column hostName in TableA(This case always happen in tableA) i compare it to Hostname to the other tables. But if there is not "." in Hostname of TableA i compare it to the column Name of the 2 others table.

what i have for now is like:

```
select IPAddress, HostName,
SUM(case when tbl = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) TableB,
SUM(case when tbl = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) TableC,
SUM(case when tbl = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) TableA
from
(
    select IPAdress, HostName,'a' tbl
    from TableB
    union all
    select IPAdress, HostName,'b' tbl
    from TableC
    union all
    select IPAdress, HostName,'c' tbl
    from TableA
) d
group by IPAddress, HostName
```

It works well but i don't know how to compare on others table depends if there a "." in the column Hostname in TableA.

**#Edit1:**

```
Table A:
IpAddress    |HostName
10.10.01.10  | somethingtada
255.255.255.1| something.else
255.10.10.1  | bliblio
1.1.1.1      | tada
2.2.2.2      | tada3.tada
2.2.2.2      | tada5.tada

Table B:
IpAddress    |HostName            |Name
10.10.01.10  |somethingtada.tada  |somethingtada
255.1.1.1    |test3.test          |test3
126.126.126.1|test4.test          |test4
2.2.2.2      |tada5.tada          |tada5

Table C:
IpAddress    |HostName        |Name
255.255.255.1| something.else |something
1.1.1.1      | blabla.tada    |blabla
255.1.1.1    | test3.test     |test3
3.3.3.3      | test5.test     |test5
```

And I need to have a table that show me the data like that

```
IpAddress    |HostName          |TableA|TableB|TableC
10.10.01.10  |somethingtada.tada|1     |1     |0
255.255.255.1|something.else    |1     |0     |1
1.1.1.1      |blabla.tada       |1     |0     |1
255.10.10.1  |blibio            |1     |0     |0
255.1.1.1    |test3.test        |0     |1     |1
126.126.126.1|test4.test        |0     |1     |0
2.2.2.2      |tada3.tada        |1     |0     |0
3.3.3.3      |test5.test        |0     |0     |1
2.2.2.2      |tada5.tada        |1     |1     |0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should happen if `A.HostName` matches neither `HostName` nor `Name` in the other two tables? What should the output be?

Comment: We will see the data of IpAddress ans HostName, under TableB And TableC its we will have a "0" and under tableA We will have "1"

Comment: To clarify, I meant the situation when `A.IPAddress` has a match in either `B.IPAddress` or `C.IPAddress` but the corresponding `A.HostName` has no match. So, if what you said still stands, the output would contain more than one entry for that IP Address, one with `TableA = 1` and `TableB = TableC = 0` and the other(s) with `TableA = 0` and either `TableB = 1` or `TableC = 1` (or both). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's it. Cause that means of we have 2 different things

Comment: In the example given, it looks like matching `IPAddress` would be sufficient to generate the desired output. Is that not the case generally?

Comment: Can there be a case like this: `B` has an entry of `IP1, HostNameA, Name1`, `C` has `IP1, HostNameB, Name1`, `A` has `IP1, Name1`? Which of the `HostName`s should the `A` entry be identified with? In general, if a `B` entry of `(IP, HostName)` matches an entry in `C`, is there a guarantee that their `Name` values match too? And similarly, if there are matching entries of `(IP, Name)` in `B` and `C`, is it definite that the `HostName`s will also match?

Comment: As you can see in my "#edit1:" that's what i expect to have in my table and that's the result that i need to have. Hope it helps

Comment: Somebody have an idea? Cause I really need to do this.

Comment: What if `TableA` has `somethingtada` as well as `somethingtada.tada` and `somethingtada.com`, could `TableB` have just the latter two `HostNames`, both showing `somethingtada` as the `Name`? How should they be correlated, then?

Comment: I've fixed a couple of inconsistencies in your post. However, your expected output still has issues. In particular, there's a `1.1.1.1      | tada` row in `TableA` and no output row seems to match it. On the other hand, there's a `1.1.1.1      |blabla.tada` with `TableA` value of 1. But why is `tada` considered to be matching `blabla.tada`?

Comment: @ErikE: You seem to be reading the question slightly differently. I didn't notice anything about *partial* matching of `TableA.HostName` against `TableB.HostName` or `TableC.HostName`. However, it only proves that there are still unresolved issues about this question, and my answer, therefore, may be incomplete.

Comment: @AndriyM I did edit my comment to make it clearer. But let me restate: How would `somethingtada` from `TableA` match to just one row if there are two possible dotted `HostName`s for it to match to in `TableB`, `somethingtada.tada` and `somethingtada.com` (since they both would have a `Name` of `somethingtada`)? I wasn't talking about *actually* matching partially--but the fact is that when there is no dot, one is to match to the `Name` column, which is *in effect* a partial match to the `HostName` column.

Comment: @ErikE: Well, my assumption was that there didn't have to be a correlation between `HostName` and `Name` of the kind you are talking about. In any event, I was assuming that the name would be unique (or at least `IPAddress` *and* `Name` would be unique).

Comment: JoSav: please tell us the DBMS and version you're using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, postgresql, etc.)! @AndriyM I guess the OP will have to tell us.

Comment: I have a SQL Compact Edition (.sdf) as Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing this part:

```
select AdresseIP, HostName,'c' tbl
from TableA
```

with something like this:

```
SELECT
  IPAddress,
  COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN HostName NOT LIKE '%.%' THEN
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 HostName
        FROM (
          SELECT HostName
          FROM TableB
          WHERE IPAddress = TableA.IPAdress
            AND Name = TableA.HostName
          UNION ALL
          SELECT HostName
          FROM TableC
          WHERE IPAddress = TableA.IPAdress
            AND Name = TableA.HostName
        ) s
      )
    END,
    HostName
  ) AS HostName,
  'c' AS tbl
FROM TableA
```

It works like this. For every row in `TableA`, if `HostName` doesn't have a `.` in it (`NOT LIKE '%.%'`), the query looks up both `TableB` and `TableC` for `HostName` where the corresponding `IPAddress` and `Name` match the current `TableA` row's `IPAddress` and `HostName`. The results from the two tables are then combined and one value of the united set is returned to substitute the current row's `HostName`.

The current row's `HostName` itself is used instead of the above when it does have a `.` or if no matching `HostName` in the other two tables was found.

To clarify, this is how the entire query would like after replacing the part I mentioned in the beginning:

```
select IPAddress, HostName,
SUM(case when tbl = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) TableB,
SUM(case when tbl = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) TableC,
SUM(case when tbl = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) TableA
from
(
    select AdresseIP, HostName,'a' tbl
    from TableB
    union all
    select AdresseIP, HostName,'b' tbl
    from TableC
    union all
    SELECT
      IPAddress,
      COALESCE(
        CASE WHEN HostName NOT LIKE '%.%' THEN
          (
            SELECT TOP 1 HostName
            FROM (
              SELECT HostName
              FROM TableB
              WHERE IPAddress = TableA.IPAdress
                AND Name = TableA.HostName
              UNION ALL
              SELECT HostName
              FROM TableC
              WHERE IPAddress = TableA.IPAdress
                AND Name = TableA.HostName
            ) s
          )
        END,
        HostName
      ) AS HostName,
      'c' AS tbl
    FROM TableA
) d
group by IPAddress, HostName
;
```

And please don't hold your breath about the performance. However, maybe this will give you some ideas and you'll eventually find a better solution.

Comment: i forgot to mentionne it and i'm sorry for it. I use a Sql server compact edition (.sdf) it's local database for my application

Comment: When i try to test your solution, i got some error like: There was an error parsing the query.[Token line number = 18, Token line offset =13, Token in error = SELECT]". I'd replace the "Top 1" for Top (1) * and still have an error.

Comment: I forgot to put `HostName` after `TOP 1`. Please take a look now.

Comment: i cant for the moment but i will tomorrow morning

Comment: When I test this query without any schema, I get [only errors about missing objects](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15230). That means, this is valid T-SQL, because name resolution is done *after* syntax check. However, if you still get complaints about syntactical errors, that may mean that I've hit some restriction of the T-SQL subset that SQL Server CE uses. And if that is the case, I'm afraid I can't help you there, as I don't have a SQL Server CE handy to verify/modify the script. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
select
  coalesce(a.ipaddress, b.ipaddress, c.ipaddress),
  coalesce(b.hostname, c.hostname, a.hostname),
  case when a.ipaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end,
  case when b.ipaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end,
  case when c.ipaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end
from
  tablea a
  full join tableb b on
    a.ipaddress = b.ipaddress and (
      (a.hostname like '%.%' and a.hostname = b.hostname) or
      (a.hostname not like '%.%' and a.hostname = b.name)
    )
  full join tablec c on
    a.ipaddress = c.ipaddress and (
      (a.hostname like '%.%' and a.hostname = c.hostname) or
      (a.hostname not like '%.%' and a.hostname = c.name)
    )
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c917/2/0)

**EDIT:** Andriy M's suggested improvements sound good to me. Here's the full improved version:

```
select
  coalesce(a.ipaddress, b.ipaddress, c.ipaddress),
  coalesce(b.hostname, c.hostname, a.hostname),
  case when a.ipaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end,
  case when b.ipaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end,
  case when c.ipaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end
from
  tablea a
  full join tableb b on
    a.ipaddress = b.ipaddress and (
      (a.hostname like '%.%' and a.hostname = b.hostname) or
      (a.hostname not like '%.%' and a.hostname = b.name)
    )
  full join tablec c on
    coalesce(a.ipaddress, b.ipaddress) = c.ipaddress and (
      (a.hostname like '%.%' and a.hostname = c.hostname) or
      (a.hostname not like '%.%' and a.hostname = c.name) or
      (a.hostname is null and b.hostname = c.hostname)
    )
```

I don't have time to go update the sqlfiddle and test it, but you should be able to see a difference if you run it on the larger input. The output row with `TableA=0 TableB=1 TableC=1` would not be correctly joined by my original query, but it should be fixed in the updated query.

Comment: The full joins might work. The join condition on `tablec`, however, should probably be expanded to include `tableb`. The IP address comparison, in particular, should be something like `coalesce(a.ipaddress, b.ipaddress) = c.ipaddress` and there needs to be a third disjunctive member, something along the lines of `...or (a.hostname is null and b.hostname = c.hostname)...`.

Comment: @AndriyM your improvements look good to me and I've updated the ansswer